# How to get the attribute value of "id" from the anchor tag by class name when its clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $("#jqxTree-ReportGroups ul").append("<li id=" + [data[i].Id] + " item-checked='true' item-expanded='true' class='treeLi'> 
<a class='report-tree-expand'  href=''>+</a> 
<a class='reportData' id='12345' href=''>" + [data[i].Name] + "</a></li>");
```

How to get the attribute value of "id" by class name "reportData" when its clicked?

EDIT:
     click doesnt work.. If i use Live that function is getting called... How to do get the reportData's Id inside a live function

Comment: this means that you are using the click function before the content was on the page .. you have to append the string before using the click method ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this Code:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.reportData' , function(){
   var idProp= $(this).prop('id'); // or attr() 
    var idAttr = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('using prop = ' + idProp + ' , using attr  = ' + idAttr);
    console.log();
   return false; // to prevent the default action of the link also prevents bubbling 
});
```

done use live it has been deprecated (on requires jquery version 1.7 and above)
but here is the code using live()

```
$('.reportData').live('click' , function(){
   var idProp= $(this).prop('id'); // or attr() 
    var idAttr = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('using prop = ' + idProp + ' , using attr  = ' + idAttr);
    console.log();
   return false; // to prevent the default action of the link also prevents bubbling 
});
```

jsfiddle to prove working

http://jsfiddle.net/uvgW4/1/

Comment: as @vinod says , it depends on the jquery version and the browser ... in explorer only prop works (as far as i can remember) .. i will update the answer

Comment: correction im sorry .. prop doesnt depend on the jquery version `version added: 1.6` so it is old method .. only depends on the browser as i remember form past experience . so for id always use prop()

Comment: But its not working in my case. Not even calling the $('.reportData').click(function()) when it is clicked...

Comment: can you please suggest me how to get this using live() .

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$(document).on("click", ".reportDatan", function() {
    var id = this.id;
});
```

Use event delegation since it looks like your adding this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.reportDatan').click(function(){
$(this).attr('id');    
});
```

if you are using jquery 1.9

```
$('.reportDatan').click(function(){
$(this).prop('id');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation of HTML String inside jQuery is wrong, take a look at this Code which has live function or if you want this to be readable, you can use JavaScript Template Engine [`Mustache`](http://mustache.github.io/) also

HTML:

```
<div id="jqxTree-ReportGroups">
    <ul>
        <li>First</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var yourLiID = 100;
   var aValue = 'Report Data';
   var yourLi = "<li id='" + yourLiID + "' item-checked='true' item-expanded='true' class='treeLi'>";
   var yourAnchor = "<a class='report-tree-expand'  href=''>Your Text</a> ";
   var secondAnchor = "<a class='reportData' id='12345' href=''>" + aValue + "</a>";
   var yourLiClose = '</li>';
   $("#jqxTree-ReportGroups ul").append(yourLi + yourAnchor + secondAnchor + yourLiClose);

    $('.reportData').live("click", function(){
      var yourAnchorID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert('yourAnchorID: ' + yourAnchorID);
      return false;
    });

});
```

Refer this [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/j4bPY/) Link for demo

Comment: That was a very clean explanation..tried it. not working.. can achieve same functionality. but coudn get Id.

Comment: when it is clicked it goes to the this line line "$('.reportData').click(function()" , But before entering into this function , I am getting DOMException in the js file i am using.. It is  jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: Check my code, it has live function, edit the JSfiddle or share your code